# How can I put my Android app in the blackberry market?

Tags: android, blackberry

I have Android apps and I would like to port them to Blackbarry decives so I can also distribute them on the blackberry app store.  What is the best way to do that? Is it possible?  Or do I have to re-write the whole app in blackberry code whatever that is :)

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: If you have to say, " blackberry code whatever that is ", then you should probably do some more research on the topic before posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the whole "Blackberry code, whatever that is" comment, I'm going to assume you haven't programmed this in SenchaTouch, or PhoneGap, or some other mobile unification type of language based in HTML5.  As such, I'm assuming you have used native Android APIs.  Therefore, the answer is you have are likely to have to re-write your application.  Though there is a little bit of hope.

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/.

Some applications can be ported, but it's not guaranteed to work, it depends on which version of the Android tools/apis your application uses and the type of application that you developed.  It is likely to require at least a little re-tooling regardless.  If this leads to a dead end you have to re-write your application.

http://developer.blackberry.com/

As referenced in the comments, you have a little more research to do.  The site above is a good place to start.

Comment: my app is actually a productivity-type app. It isn't a complex game or anything.  So maybe there is hope for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite your apps to expose to Blackberry. If you want to write your application just once and export to Android and Blackberry (IOS too... at least it says the docs) you can test [Titanium.](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Comment: You failed to mention that there are options that involve porting for simple productivity type of apps.  In my experience it's usually a clunky process that involves some debugging and modifying, removal of some features, but it's not a completely lost cause.

Answer (score 0):

Natively written Android apps can be 'easily' converted to BlackBerry using:

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/apk-compatibility-check

You don't have to have had the Android app written in PhoneGap, html5, etc.

There are plenty of modules/frameworks that are not compatible unfortunately so often there is some tweaking to do. As an example, if your Android app uses Bluetooth, you won't be able to port without some changes.

However, simpler apps can be easily ported. As an example, a very commonly used sample app provided by Android is called ApiDemos (if you haven't used it, just search for it and download the .apk). In the link I provided, you can browse to the apk and your android-sdks folder and start the compatibility test and you'll see it passes. That is, once that's done, it's literally a repackaging/signing exercise with no code changes needed!

Comment: This answer is essentially a duplicate of mine.  The compatibility check link, however, is a good additional resource.